# Grep match exact string

Tags: regex, string, grep

```
file.txt
example=0x12; non-match 

grep -w "example=0x0" file.txt
```

I am trying to match exact string using grep and it looks like
echo $? always returns 1.

In this case, the output should have been 0. I have tried -F too.

Comment: How can `0x0` match `0x12` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `-q` option if you're just checking the exit status.  See below for examples

```
$ grep -qw "A" <<< "AAA"; echo $?
1
$ grep -qw "A" <<< "A"; echo $?
0
```

first word match fails, exit 1.  Second one succeeds, exit 0.